# Low FPS on nexus 6 fw 5.0 until call onPause of GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, frame-rate, glsurfaceview

I have a problem with my game running on nexus 6, the FPS is very low.
But after an interrupt the FPS is became normal, it increase from 6-10 to 26-30. After checking, I notice that FPS increased after calling onPause of GLSurfaceView.

- It just occurs on nexus 6, my nexus 5 fw 5.0 run normally
- I removed FPS limit to avoid some function like currentTimeMillis, but it doesn't help.

Anyone met similar issue? Any advises for me to solve it please.

Comment: If possible, use systrace to profile the system and try to identify the source of the trouble.

Comment: Investigate deeply, I see FPS increase after re-creating EGL context

Comment: @fadden the poor lost souls that make up the Android graphics app dev community miss your contributions dearly! Come back to us ;)

Comment: FPS issue was solved by using VBO as much as posible, I didn't try that before since "the FPS increase after re-creating EGL context" :))
BTW this is fw bug, it's gone if up nx6 to 5.1

Answer (score 0):

FPS issue was solved by using VBO as much as posible, I didn't try that before since "the FPS increase after re-creating EGL context" :)) 
BTW this is fw bug, it's gone if up nx6 to 5.1